# next InitializeSecurityContext failed - SSL CONNECTION using pycurl

Tags: python, ssl, curl, pycurl

I'm struggling to translate command like this below

`curl "https://my.website.address.com" --key path\to\client_key.pem --cert path\to\client.crt --pass P4$$w0rD`

to a python script using pycurl:

```
import pycurl
        URL = "https://my.website.address.com"
        KEY_PATH = "path\to\client_key.pem"
        CERT_PATH = "path\to\client.crt"
        CA_PATH = "path\to\curl-ca-bundle.crt"
        USERNAME = "my_username"
        PASSWORD = "P4$$w0rD"   

        c = pycurl.Curl()
        c.setopt(pycurl.URL, URL)
        c.setopt(pycurl.SSLKEY, KEY_PATH)
        c.setopt(pycurl.PASSWORD, PASSWORD)
        c.setopt(pycurl.SSLCERT, CERT_PATH)
        c.setopt(pycurl.USERNAME, USERNAME)
        c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2)
        c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, True)
        c.setopt(pycurl.CAINFO, CA_PATH)
        c.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, True)
        c.perform()
        c.close()
```

So let us agree that IP address for www.my.webiste.address.com is 667.667.667.667 ;)

I always get this error when I run the script:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 667.667.667.667...
* Connected to my.webiste.address.com (667.667.667.667) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with my.webiste.address.com port 443 (step 1/3)
* schannel: checking server certificate revocation
* schannel: sending initial handshake data: sending 204 bytes...
* schannel: sent initial handshake data: sent 204 bytes
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with my.webiste.address.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: failed to receive handshake, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with my.webiste.address.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 1260 length 4096
* schannel: encrypted data length: 1162
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 1162 length 4096
* schannel: received incomplete message, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with my.webiste.address.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 3157 length 4096
* schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_I_INCOMPLETE_CREDENTIALS (0x00090320) - The credentials supplied were not complete, and could not be verified. Additional information can be returned from the context.
* Closing connection 0
* schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with my.webiste.address.com port 443

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/path/to/project/main.py", line 59, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/path/to/project/main.py, line 51, in main
    c.perform()

pycurl.error: (35, 'schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_I_INCOMPLETE_CREDENTIALS (0x00090320) - The credentials supplied were not complete, and could not be verified. Additional information can be returned from the context.')

* schannel: clear security context handle
* schannel: clear credential handle
```

Do you know how it should looks properly?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?  I'm experiencing a similar issue in libcurl w/ schannel via C++

Comment: I am also having the same problem with C++ using libcurl
=========
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 2761 length 16384
* schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_I_INCOMPLETE_CREDENTIALS
(0x00090320) - The credentials supplied were not complete, and could not be veri
fied. Additional information can be returned from the context.
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 16384

Answer (score 0):

Issue I found was in my own code-

Instead of client_key.c_str() I was passing in client_key an std::string; which was compiling fine since curl_easy_setopt is a macro. However I should have been passing const char *.

=========================

```
if (RestClientClass::client_key.size()) {
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, RestClientClass::client_key.c_str());
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE, "PEM");
}

if (RestClientClass::client_certificate.size()) {
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, RestClientClass::client_certificate.c_str());
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, "PEM");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
}
```